# Esri cache white tiles levels L10 L11 L12 with Geowebcache

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-2, geowebcache

I'm trying to publish a WMTS using the basemap from Esri cached tile. The cache is called by geowebcache 1.7.2 and displayed via a openlayers view.

The problem I deal with is that the levels L10/L11/L12 of my basemap are displayed in white whereas all of the other levels of tiles are working well.
Nothing appears in the logs of geowebcache or in firebug (F12).
Do you have any idea about this problem?